# Get item value from infinity RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have made a three infinity RecyclerView (100, 60, 60 item count):

```
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
```

Now I want to get item value from this Views. And for 100 item count RecyclerView its easy, but I dont understand how to make this for 60 item count RecyclerView. I made a method in Adapter, like this:

```
public String get(int position) {
        return hours.get(position).hour;
    }
```

Here is for 100:

```
        hours.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == recyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    View centerView = snapHelper.findSnapView(linearLayoutManager);
                    int pos = linearLayoutManager.getPosition(centerView);
                    String val = recyclerAdapter.get(pos % 100);
                    Log.e("Snapped Item Position:","" + val);
                }
            }
        });
```

Maybe there is better way to get item values from infinity RecyclerView?

Here u can check the project on GitHub: [InfinityRecycler](https://github.com/rostslv/SnappedRecycler)

Comment: Why just not use [TimePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker)?

Comment: I want to make the application like timer in Samsung Clock, because it's very beautiful